# Zend Framework 2 with DOMPDFModule

Tags: php, zend-framework2, dompdf

I'm trying to export data from MySQL table using DOMPDFModule module, but I get this message:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in D:\www\autodbzend\vendor\dompdf\dompdf\include\text_renderer.cls.php on line 36
```

When I printout SQL query result in view, it works perfect.

Any suggestion?

Comment: The issue could be an overly complex document that requires more time (in which case one of the answers provided should help) or it could be some other problem (such as a bug in dompdf). It would help to see a code sample to help decipher what's going happening.

Answer (score 1):

First, stop generating PDF files in your HTTP requests (assuming you're doing this). Use something like SlmQueue to asynchronously process the PDFs via CLI.

Then, the CLI has no set timeout for 30 seconds, so you can keep it running longer. Monitor job speed and memory usage, as the DOM pdf should be able to generate pdf files in CLI this way.

Comment: Where to find a real example with SlmQueu, and how it works with PDF generating?

Comment: There is no open commercial software as far as I know, but it isn't difficult to put the documentation pieces from SlmQueue and the Dompdf module together.

Comment: I got this message `Socket error 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
 (connecting to 127.0.0.1:11300) ` What it means?

Comment: @Blagi that is a typical Beanstalkd error. SlmQueueBeanstalkd uses Pheanstalk. This php client is unable to connect to the beanstalkd server. Either the Pheanstalk config is incorrect, or the beanstalkd service isn't running or running on another port.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your query is taking more than 30 seconds to execute, and PHP is killing it. You could either improve your code so that to get your tabe in less than 30 seconds, or increase the php time limit as follows :

```
set_time_limit(200); // set to 200 seconds
```

You could also set it to unlimited time like this :

```
set_time_limit(-1); //set to unlimited time limit
```